# Is the map $L^{1}_{loc}\left( \mathbb{R}^{n} \right) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{D}^{\prime}\left( \mathbb{R}^{n} \right)$ a topological embedding?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and denote by $L^{1}_{loc}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$ the space of locally integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and by $\mathcal{D}^{\prime}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$ the space of distributions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ that we endow with their usual topologies. It is well known that the map $I \colon L^{1}_{loc}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right) \rightarrow \mathcal{D}^{\prime}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$ given by $$\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right), \, \left\langle I(f), \varphi \right\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f \varphi \, d\lambda$$ is a continuous injective linear map, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\mathcal{D}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$ denotes the space of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with compact support. Is this map a topological embedding? Equivalently, if $\left( f_{n} \right)_{n \geq 0}$ is a sequence of elements of $L^{1}_{loc}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right)$ such that $$\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{D}\left( \mathbb{R}^{d} \right), \, \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f_{n} \varphi \, d \lambda = 0 \, \text{,}$$ then do we have necessarily $$\forall K \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} \text{ compact}, \, \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{K} \left\lvert f_{n} \right\rvert \, d\lambda = 0 \, \text{?}$$ I could not find the answer in the literature. I would be surprised if this question has a positive answer, but I have not been able to construct a counterexample.

Comment: Confusing to use $n$ both in $\mathbb R^n$ and in $f_n$.  I assume you did not really mean this weird thing: $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f_{n} \varphi \, d \lambda.$$

Comment: Isn't the last formula missing a comparison? $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{K} \left\lvert f_{n} \right\rvert \, d\lambda < \infty$$

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar and @md2perpe! I have edited my question.

Comment: For all these embedding theorems in analysis, of some small space inside a big space, as a rule these are never topological embeddings. This is because, in order to be useful, these spaces are complete. But we also want the small space to be dense in the big space. So something has got to give: the topology induced by the big space on the small space must be weaker than the natural topology of the small space.

Comment: To make Abdelamalek's very good remark a proof, note that $L^1_{loc}$ is dense in $\mathscr D'$ (even much smaller spaces like that of test functions are dense). If the embedding were topological, the completeness of $L^1_{loc}$ would imply $\mathscr D'=L^1_{loc}$ which is of course not true since, e.g., the dirac distribution $\delta_0$ is not in $L^1_{loc}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this.
In $\mathbb R$ .
For $k \in \mathbb N$, let
$$
f_k = k\mathbf1_{(0,1/k)} \qquad\text{and}\qquad g_k = k\mathbf1_{(-1/k,0)}
$$
so that as $k \to \infty$ we have $f_k \to \delta$ and $g_k \to \delta$ in $\mathcal D'$.
Then consider $h_k = f_k-g_k$.  So $h_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal D'$.  But for $K = [-1,1]$, we have $\int_K |h_k| = 2 \not\to 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $g_k = k\mathbf1_{(-1/k,0)}$ (i.e. $k$ instead of $n$)?

Comment: Is it really correct that $h_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'$?

Comment: Thank you very much @GEdgar! It was not that hard finally :).

Comment: To @md2perpe: the answer has been edited.

Comment: thanks for the edit